# Solve an angr function with string parameters

Tags: angr

Look at this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_function(char *s);

int my_function(char *s)
{
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
       s[i]++;
    }
    if (strncmp(s,"b{fsuz",6)==0)
    {
       return 1; 
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    // Lot of stuff, including UI
    if (my_function(argv[1])==1)
    {
        printf("Good\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong !\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What i want to do is to make a symbolic analysis on my_function (and only this function) with angr.

Here is the function disassembly:

```
|           ; var int local_28h @ rbp-0x28
|           ; var int local_14h @ rbp-0x14
|           ; CALL XREF from 0x000011e7 (main)
|           0x00001155      55             push rbp
|           0x00001156      4889e5         mov rbp, rsp
|           0x00001159      53             push rbx
|           0x0000115a      4883ec28       sub rsp, 0x28               ; '('
|           0x0000115e      48897dd8       mov qword [local_28h], rdi
|           0x00001162      c745ec000000.  mov dword [local_14h], 0
|       ,=< 0x00001169      eb19           jmp 0x1184
|      .--> 0x0000116b      8b45ec         mov eax, dword [local_14h]
|      :|   0x0000116e      4863d0         movsxd rdx, eax
|      :|   0x00001171      488b45d8       mov rax, qword [local_28h]
|      :|   0x00001175      4801d0         add rax, rdx                ; '('
|      :|   0x00001178      0fb610         movzx edx, byte [rax]
|      :|   0x0000117b      83c201         add edx, 1
|      :|   0x0000117e      8810           mov byte [rax], dl
|      :|   0x00001180      8345ec01       add dword [local_14h], 1
|      :|   ; JMP XREF from 0x00001169 (sym.my_function)
|      :`-> 0x00001184      8b45ec         mov eax, dword [local_14h]
|      :    0x00001187      4863d8         movsxd rbx, eax
|      :    0x0000118a      488b45d8       mov rax, qword [local_28h]
|      :    0x0000118e      4889c7         mov rdi, rax
|      :    0x00001191      e8bafeffff     call sym.imp.strlen         ; size_t strlen(const char *s)
|      :    0x00001196      4839c3         cmp rbx, rax
|      `==< 0x00001199      72d0           jb 0x116b
|           0x0000119b      488b45d8       mov rax, qword [local_28h]
|           0x0000119f      ba06000000     mov edx, 6
|           0x000011a4      488d35590e00.  lea rsi, str.b_fsuz         ; 0x2004 ; "b{fsuz"
|           0x000011ab      4889c7         mov rdi, rax
|           0x000011ae      e87dfeffff     call sym.imp.strncmp        ; int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
|           0x000011b3      85c0           test eax, eax
|       ,=< 0x000011b5      7507           jne 0x11be
|       |   0x000011b7      b801000000     mov eax, 1
|      ,==< 0x000011bc      eb05           jmp 0x11c3
|      |`-> 0x000011be      b800000000     mov eax, 0
|      |    ; JMP XREF from 0x000011bc (sym.my_function)
|      `--> 0x000011c3      4883c428       add rsp, 0x28               ; '('
|           0x000011c7      5b             pop rbx
|           0x000011c8      5d             pop rbp
\           0x000011c9      c3             ret
```

What i want is to ask angr: Which string should i pass in parameter to my_function in order to get a return of 1.

Here is what i've done:

```
import angr

base = 0x400000
function_start = base + 0x00001155 # 0x0000115e
function_target = base + 0x000011b7
function_end = base + 0x000011be

p = angr.Project("./a.out")
state = p.factory.blank_state(addr=function_start)
a = state.solver.BVS('a', 8*7)
# state.memory.store(state.regs.rbp-0x28,a)
state.memory.store(state.regs.rdi,a)

sm = p.factory.simulation_manager(state)
sm.explore(find=function_target, avoid=function_end)

found_path = sm.found[0]
print(found_path.state.se.any_str(a))
```

It displays "a{fsuz" but the good answer is "azerty".

What is wrong ?

Second question: why does angr not found anything if i put 0x00001156 address as function start ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a couple of errors there.

First, and this one shouldn't be too critical, is that your start address is not the function's entry (at `0x00001155`). That may have been your intention when you were writing the BVS to the stack, but it is unnecessary now.

The second and more critical issue is that the BVS `a` is 6 bytes long, while it should be 7 bytes long to include the null terminator value that is required for strings of 6 non-null characters for angr's `strlen` implementation to function properly.

Comment: I do not understand why i should start at the function start. Why shouldn't start at 0x0000115e ?

Comment: see my edit, i have changed python code

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in how you declare that string to angr. I started with your example code and checked if it works when I assign some address for the argument witch is checked. My best guess is that

```
state.memory.store(state.regs.rdi,a)
```

Does not do what you expect it to do.
Here is the full solution (addresses may differ):

```
# coding: utf8
import angr

function_start = 0x400590
function_target = 0x400603
function_end = 0x400616
dummy_addr = 0x300000

p = angr.Project("./a.out")
state = p.factory.blank_state(addr=function_start)
a = state.solver.BVS('a', 8 * 7)
state.memory.store(dummy_addr, a)
state.regs.rdi = dummy_addr

sm = p.factory.simulation_manager(state)
sm.explore(find=function_target, avoid=function_end)

found_path = sm.found[0]
print found_path.state.se.eval(a, cast_to=bytes)
```

**edit**

stack solution as requested

Please note my variables are located at a different offset (clang/gcc)

```
# coding: utf8
import angr

function_start = 0x40059c
function_target = 0x400603
function_end = 0x400616
dummy_addr = 0x300000

p = angr.Project("./a.out")
state = p.factory.blank_state(addr=function_start)
a = state.solver.BVS('a', 8 * 7)
state.memory.store(dummy_addr, a)
state.mem[state.regs.rbp-0x10].uint64_t = dummy_addr

sm = p.factory.simulation_manager(state)
sm.explore(find=function_target, avoid=function_end)

found_path = sm.found[0]
print found_path.state.se.eval(a, cast_to=bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks but i do not understand what is dummy_addr

Comment: @Bob5421 It could be any address which is not used for something else. You want the register to hold the address of the string, not the string itself.

Comment: okay i see. In fact i tell angr to look into another address and this is in this address i put my symbolic variable. Is there a way to put the symbolic variable in place ?

Comment: @Bob5421 you mean to get a random free or an symbolic address directly from angr? Not as far as I know, but you could use any address. The store command maps the variable to the address

Comment: no i mean can i register directly my symbolic variable to local_28h (in the stack).

Comment: @Bob5421 The function expects a pointer to a char array as an argument, not the char array itself. But you could write the dummy_addr to the stack at this location with something like `state.memory.store(state.regs.rbp-0x28,dummy_addr)`

Comment: I have tried, and i started at 0x00001162, but it does not found anything. (i have put state.memory.store(state.regs.rbp-0x28,dummy_addr) and state.memory.store(dummy_addr, a)), that's it ?

Comment: @Bob5421 see my edit. it should work with `state.mem[state.regs.rbp-0x28].uint64_t = dummy_addr`

Comment: it doesn't work. It do not give me any result. can you give us the disassembly of your program ? Because i do not know which deals with 0x40059c address. Thanks

Comment: @Bob5421 its offset 0xc from the real function start at 0x400590. Should be 0x00001162 for you

Comment: I have tried this address. It does not found anything. I have just change the 3 addresses (function start, function target, function end). And i have set state.mem[state.regs.rbp-0x28].uint64_t = dummy_addr